# Optimistic concurrency in Azre iOS client SDK

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a query regarding concurrency in Azure mobile client SDK.

for windows I found [Conflict link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#optimisticconcurrency) for handling concurrency but I could not found the same for iOS client SDK.

Can anyone please suggest or help how to handle concurrency in iOS client SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [old Mobile Services page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-ios-handling-conflicts-offline-data.md) for handling conflicts with the iOS SDK. The setup for offline sync with the iOS SDK hasn't changed since then.

1) Set up an [MSSyncContextDelegate](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-services/iOS/v3/Protocols/MSSyncContextDelegate.html) and pass it to the MSSyncContext constructor when you create it.
2) Implement `tableOperation:(MSTableOperation *)operation onComplete:(MSSyncItemBlock)completion` in your delegate. After executing the operation, check for an `MSErrorPreconditionFailed` error code and decide what to do from there based on your app's needs.

```
- (void)tableOperation:(MSTableOperation *)operation onComplete:(MSSyncItemBlock)completion
{
    [operation executeWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *serverItem = [error.userInfo objectForKey:MSErrorServerItemKey];

        if (error.code == MSErrorPreconditionFailed) {
            QSUIAlertViewWithBlock *alert = [[QSUIAlertViewWithBlock alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                if (buttonIndex == 1) { // Client
                    NSMutableDictionary *adjustedItem = [operation.item mutableCopy];

                    [adjustedItem setValue:[serverItem objectForKey:MSSystemColumnVersion] forKey:MSSystemColumnVersion];
                    operation.item = adjustedItem;

                    [self doOperation:operation complete:completion];
                    return;

                } else if (buttonIndex == 2) { // Server
                    NSDictionary *serverItem = [error.userInfo objectForKey:MSErrorServerItemKey];
                    completion(serverItem, nil);
                } else { // Cancel
                    [operation cancelPush];
                    completion(nil, error);
                }
            }];

            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Client value: %@\nServer value: %@", operation.item[@"text"], serverItem[@"text"]];

            [alert showAlertWithTitle:@"Server Conflict"
                              message:message
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                    otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Use Client", @"Use Server", nil]];
        } else {
            completion(item, error);
        }
    }];
}
```